# Simple Animation in DirectX 10

Tags: animation, directx

I am a beginner in DirectX. I would like to know how to implement some animation like moving a persons hand, etc in directX 10. I have googled this question and have found out you need use stuff like bone, character animation. But, I haven't found anything which explains it properly.

I have gone through some question in stackoverflow and other forums but, I am not able to understand how to implement animation.

Also, I have gone through the Skinning10 sample in DirectX SDK. I'm not able to understand what is done there.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Directx10 sample you are referring to is rather good, but as you have found it does really require some prior knowledge of the foundation subject matter to get going. Although bone animation using the GPU is very common now it is still a topic that requires an above average knowledge of 3D graphics (data-structures used, shaders etc).

If you consider yourself already at this level then I will recommend the book below, however it is for DirectX9 not DirectX10.
Why am I recommending this if it is not what you asked for? Because in my opinion it does a good job of allowing you to understand the theory and concepts. It is also easier to do in DX9 than it is DX10, and it is therefore good practice and will allow you to transition to the DX10 way of doing this - because you will better understand the overall approach (even if coding in DX10 is somewhat different).

Book: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Character-Animation-With-Direct3D-Granberg/dp/1584505702/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1336123055&sr=8-2
Description says it is DX10, it isn't, it is DX9.

Additional to my half-answer to what you want, I would encourage you to read any material on 3d gfx, whether it be for DirectX or OpenGL - it will all help you to understand it better as the concepts span the different technology APIs, it is really just the coding approach that differs (which imo is easier to pickup once you know what it is doing).

Comment: thank. i have checked this book out, but maybe ill go through it again. Could you also just explain the theory behind how you can animate an object in 3d ( is it done in shaders or something else ? )

Comment: Look for sources on "Skinning", e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444432/simple-animation-in-directx-10/10446341#comment13782353_10446341)